# How to combine JS API URL calls?

Tags: here-api

In Google maps I can load all libraries I need with one URL call:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing,foo,bar,baz,qux,library6,etc
```

In HERE maps I must load all the libraries (they call it modules) separately:

```
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-places.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

This is a total disaster.

How do I load all the modules I need in one URL call?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs.js?modules=core,service,bar,baz,qux,library6,etc
```

Comment: Do you have metrics to show that it is worse, compared to one concatenated version? That said, you could combine the scripts with your build system.

Comment: I'm not doing it because of the metrics. I have a SPA and i load map JS scripts on demand — with Google i can load everything i need with just single JS script file request and then create and manipulate my map; with Here i have to load three JS files and guarantee they all are loaded and only then i can create and manipulate my map. It is obviously not comfortable solution for the development.

Comment: The browser parallelizes requests per domain. In the given case of Google Maps, since modules are combined together in one script, it will wait for all the specified scripts to be downloaded before it can start parsing them. Not sure it is better in comparison to a handful of smaller requests. But in any case, I added an answer which gives a simple way to combine the HERE scripts you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any application based on the HERE Maps API for JavaScript it is necessary to load the code libraries or modules. The implementation of our basic use case requires two modules: core and service (see also HERE Maps API for [JavaScript Modules](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/overview.html#overview__modules)).
This is the minimum and cannot be avoided or summed up into one link.

The Maps API for JavaScript is organized into a number of modules to give developers the possibility to use the API efficiently by selecting only the modules which their applications require.

Comment: Ok, so the answer is NO. It is very sad, it is not comfortable solution. Will be much better to use Google's scenario — single request loads everything i need.

Answer (score 1):

As you guessed from the accepted answer, there is no endpoint which allows you to concatenate different modules of HERE Maps JavaScript API, however if it really matters for you to concatenate them, you can achieve a similar service very easily.

The following uses *curl* command to download files:

```
curl https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-{core,service,ui}.js > mapsjs-custom.js
```